# How to integrate FocusWriter into the elementary OS theming?

Tags: themes, qt

I use [FocusWriter](http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/) as my prefered distraction free writing editor. I installed it using the developer's [ppa:gottcode/gcppa](https://launchpad.net/~gottcode/+archive/ubuntu/gcppa) ppa. Being a Qt application, by default FocusWriter does not use the elementary OS's theming.

[image: FocusWriter menu]

Are there any recommendations how to better integrate FocusWriter into the elementary OS design?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: +1 Don't think it is possible, however you can try using [Uberwriter](http://productivefoss.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/introduction-well-we-will-finally.html), which, in my opinion, is even more feature packed than FocusWriter.

Comment: @Luís Unfortunately Uberwriter has not been updated since 2013.

Comment: @orschiro their launchpad website is not being update, but the author released a new version 14 weeks [ago](https://launchpad.net/~w-vollprecht/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: @Luís Thanks a lot! I will test it and see if it fits my needs.